# how to convert odbc connection to sql connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

Right now I'm using this ODBC connection and it's working :

```
try
    {
        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnStr"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM datas", connection))
            using (OdbcDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                        switch (dr["namen"].ToString())
                        {
                            case "gt": Label2.Text = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                            case "gp1": Image1.ImageUrl = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                            case "gp2": Image2.ImageUrl = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                            case "gp3": Image3.ImageUrl = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                        }
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("An error occured: " + ex.Message);
    }
```

I want to use SQL Connection so that I can fill datalist into it.

PS: I think if I could use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnStr"].ConnectionString` in 
SQLconnection it will solve my problem.

But I'm not able to think how to do it?

Comment: What database software are you using? MySQL? If so do you have the [MySQL ADO.NET connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) installed?

Comment: No what? No you don't have the connector installed but you are using MySQL, no you are not using MySQL, or no you are not using any database software? Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22104478/edit) and add the new information.

Comment: No i don't have the connector installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a few simple steps.

1. Download and install the [.NET connector for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) (you will need to include this when you deploy the program). You may want to install [MySQL for Visual Studio](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/visualstudio/) on your development machine to add features in to Visual Studio like browsing the database and editing stored procedures.
2. Include the reference `MySql.Data.dll` in your project.
3. Add `using MySql.Data;` to the top of your file.
4. Everywhere you see `Odbc` replace it with `MySql`.

So your example code becomes

```
try
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnStr"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM datas", connection))
        using (MySqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                    switch (dr["namen"].ToString())
                    {
                        case "gt": Label2.Text = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                        case "gp1": Image1.ImageUrl = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                        case "gp2": Image2.ImageUrl = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                        case "gp3": Image3.ImageUrl = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                    }
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("An error occured: " + ex.Message);
}
```

You may need to tweak the text in `MySQLConnStr` to get it to work, see [this reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/) for .NET MySQL connection strings.

Comment: now i have a problem with this web.config line :
<add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/></assemblies>
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Don't know, I would ask a new question about it, including the relevant code and error messages in the question. Does the server that is running this code have the connector installed on it?

Comment: do you mean the .dll file ? ... yes but not in the same directory , in the bin directory

Comment: It needs more than that one DLL file. notice the part about "***or one of its dependencies***"